How to check who has re-run the azure devops yaml pipeline
Assume if a scheduled azure devops YAML pipeline run fails and if anyone re-run the pipeline from the failed job. The pipeline is not able to show who has triggered the re-run.
I tried using $(Build.Requestedfor) and $(Build.QueuedBy) variables. But no luck.
Here is why, Since the pipeline got triggered initially from the schedule, the value for the above mentioned variables is shown as “[Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.TFS]” no matter how many times you re-run the pipeline from the failed job.
Is there a way how to fetch user name who had re-run the pipeline from the failed job. If not, does anyone have a work around for it.
Thanks

same question with you.....

Currently, Azure DevOps doesn't have such feature can get the user who re-run the failed job. If you check the network trace when you click Rerun failed jobs button, you will find that there isn't any related info. I noticed that you have created a ticket to Azure DevOps support, the support engineer has confirmed and explained this.
It's suggested that you follow the below feature request you have created. I have helped you submit a vote. Anyone wants this feature can vote and comment to increase the priority.
How to check who has re-run the scheduled yaml pipeline
